# Javascript - How to filter with multiple checkboxes in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filter

Here is my code for the filter, sort, and search together and everything works fine

```
<template>
  <h5>List of Products</h5>

        <h3>Filter</h3> 
        <button v-on:click="resetOptions">Reset</button>
        <button v-on:click="sorting">Sorting</button>
        <button v-on:click="sorting2">Sorting2</button>
        <select v-model="category">
            <option value="Accessories">Accessories</option>
            <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
            <option value="Stationary">Stationary</option>
        </select> 
        <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" v-model="city" value='Roma' @change="uniqueCheck">
        <label for="test"> Roma</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test2" id="test2" v-model.trim="city" value='Barselona' @change="uniqueCheck">
        <label for="test2"> Barselona</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test3" id="test3" v-model.trim="city" value='Milano' @change="uniqueCheck">
        <label for="test3"> Milano</label>
        </div>
         <!-- <select v-model="city">
            <option value="Barselona">Barselona</option>
            <option value="Roma"> Roma </option>
            <option value="Milano">Milano</option>
        </select>  -->

        <input type="text" v-model="name" placeholder="Filter By Name"/>

        <label for="vol">Price (between 0 and 1000):</label>
    
        <input type="range" v-model.trim="range" min="0" max="1000" step="10"/>  
        <ul>
            <li v-for="product in filterProducts" :key="product.name"> Product Name : {{product.name}} - Price : {{product.price}} ({{product.category}}) 
                {{product.city}}
            </li>
        </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data: ()=> ( {

           
            city:[ ],
            category: '',
            name: '',
            range: '10000',
            products: [
                { name: "Keyboard", price: 44, category: 'Accessories', city:'Roma'},
                { name: "Mouse", price: 20, category: 'Accessories', city:'Barselona'},
                { name: "Monitor", price: 399, category: 'Accessories', city:'Roma'},
                { name: "Dell XPS", price: 599, category: 'Laptop', city:'Roma'},
                { name: "MacBook Pro", price: 899, category: 'Laptop', city:'Roma'},
                { name: "Pencil Box", price: 6, category: 'Stationary', city:'Barselona'},
                { name: "Pen", price: 2, category: 'Stationary', city:'Milano'},
                { name: "USB Cable", price: 7, category: 'Accessories', city:'Milano'},
                { name: "Eraser", price: 2, category: 'Stationary', city:'Roma'},
                { name: "Highlighter", price: 5, category: 'Stationary', city:'Roma'}
            ]

        }),

              computed: {
            filterProducts: function(){
                return this.filterProductsByName(this.filterProductsByRange(this.filterProductsByCity(this.filterProductsByCategory(this.products))))
            },

        },
        
        methods: {

            filterProductsByCategory: function(products){
                return products.filter(product => !product.category.indexOf(this.category))
            },

            filterProductsByName: function(products) {
                return products.filter(product => !product.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.name.toLowerCase()))
            },

            filterProductsByCity: function(products) {
                return products.filter(product => !product.city.indexOf(this.city))
            },

            filterProductsByRange: function(products){
                return products.filter(product => (product.price >= 0 && product.price <= this.range) ? product : '')
            },

            sorting:function(){
                this.products.sort((a,b)=>(a.price > b.price) ? 1 : -1)
            },
             sorting2:function(){
                this.products.sort((a,b)=>(a.price < b.price) ? 1 : -1)
            },

            uniqueCheck(e){
            this.city = [];
            if (e.target.checked) {
                 this.city.push(e.target.value);
               }
         },

            resetOptions:function(){
                this.category='',
                this.city='',
                this.name='',
                this.range='1000'
            },
        },

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

But I want also to have multiple checkboxes filters, for example, if I checked city 'Barcelona's and 'Roma' I want to show me products with city's Barcelona and Roma. This code will not work because @change function, I tried without that but the result is this when I clicked the second checkbox I got nothing

[image]

How I can have that filter also here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filterProductsByCity method is not correct.

It should check wether the product's city is listed in your `this.city` property.

When you check your checkboxes, it will add their value to the `city` property :

ex: `['barcelona', 'montreal']`

So you could do the following:

```js
filterProductsByCity: function(products) {
    return products.filter(product => this.city.indexOf(product.city) !== -1)
}
```

Comment: This works very well but It's one problem, it's now showing the list of products by default, only when clicked. I can solve that with the default checked checkbox but I want to show the list by default and when the user check the checkbox I want the list updated with the filter function